# Windows service SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS running Qt 5.10 event loop howto

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, qt, winapi

So far I gathered:

- Windows Internals Book
- MSDN C++ service implementation sample
- Qt-Solutions QtProject/QtService

Problem is that example service from Qt-solutions is not running event loop. It is using QCoreApplication but somehow exec() does not start event loop (something with the threads ?) It must have something to do with project being somewhat old (last real update was added 3 years ago) and Qt 5.10 being somewhat new. Fix is probably not hard but I would like to understand how the whole thing could be designed. I'd prefer to find problem myself but if someone wants to check it I will accept that answer as well.

This is how I understand windows service program should look like:

There are at least two threads in this setup. First one (T1) is created for executable and entry point is usual main() which is supposed to call StartServiceCtrlDispatcher() that blocks. It passes function pointer to service main function. Let's call it SvcMain().

System will create another thread (T2) with entry point being SvcMain() which should as soon as possible run RegisterServiceCtrlHandler() to register another function as service control handler let's call it SvcCtrlHandler() and then do whatever it is supposed to be doing.

In Microsoft example SvcCtrlHandler() signals via SetSignal() / WaitForSingleObject() which is not really useful method as it will block SvcMain execution but that is not important (I think).

Questions are:

1) Qt event loop should be incorporated into second thread. Can this be done simply by creating QCoreApplication and calling exec from SvcMain() ?

2) How service manager will signal service ? Does it run SvcCtrlHandler() in thread T1 ? If that is correct then why I have to register it from T2 ?

3) If above is correct I need to create Qt event in T1 without running Qt event loop, or use some other, windows based, mechanism ?

4) I can talk back to service manager from T2 to signal it back that i've heard it ?

Comment: Use QEventLoop: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qeventloop.html if you need Qt thread serving signals/slots from other threads  (thus queued connection needed) but not UI which would want application object. If you just need some thread and not even serving signals/slots then not even QEventLoop needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How service manager will signal service ?

It (repeatedly) calls SvcCtrlHandler() with an appropriate argument (SERVICE_CONTROL_XXX). It's upon SvcCtrlHandler() to communicate with T2 (SvcMain()).

> Does it run SvcCtrlHandler() in thread T1 ? If that is correct then why I have to register it from T2 ?

Let's put it this way: SvcCtrlHandler() runs in the thread, which called StartServiceCtrlDispatcher() (usually T1). But you must register it (with RegisterServiceCtrlHandler()) only after StartServiceCtrlDispatcher() called, so you can't do it in the same thread.

> I can talk back to service manager from T2 to signal it back that i've heard it ?

Yes, by using SetServiceStatus() WinAPI, but there are different states to report to SCM. So you are allowed to call SetServiceStatus() from both SvcCtrlHandler() and SvcMain(). For example, SvcCtrlHandler() reports SERVICE_STOP_PENDING, signals to T2, and simply returns, while SvcMain() reports SERVICE_STOPPED and exits.

> Problem is that example service from Qt-solutions is not running event loop. It is using QCoreApplication but somehow exec() does not start event loop

I'm not sure which version of Qt-solutions you're looking at, but finding one (really old) in my computer, I see that they actually have it run in T1. However, there's a trick: StartServiceCtrlDispatcher() is called from the dedicated T3 thread, so T1 is not blocked by SCM. Thus we have T1 running QCoreApplication's event loop; T2 running SvcMain(); and T3 used by SCM to invoke SvcCtrlHandler() when needed.

Comment: To clarify:
Qt-solutions/qtservice uses thread T3 spawned by windows to run only RegisterServiceCtrlHandler() after that it ends. In comments they say it is recommended by MSDN documentation. MSDN example I found runs service stuff in T1 and actual program in windows spawned T2.

Server example in Qt-solutions does not work properly when compiled to AMD64 target because they used int (32bit long) as socket descriptor.

void incomingConnection(int socket)

should be :

void incomingConnection(qintptr socket)

Comment: @MariuszZieliński `MSDN example I found runs service stuff in T1` This is the most typical scenario, as services rarely need to run a message loop. But, maybe, there's also a special recommendation for services actually running it. Just guessing.

Comment: I think you are thinking about StartServiceCtrlDispatcher() - this is the call that blocks (MSDN calls it from T1; qtservice from QThread spawned T2). RegisterServiceCtrlHandler() Is the first call of working thread (MSDN runs it in windows spawned T2 and after that runs working loop; the same happens in qtservice (T3 spawned by windows) with exception that function calling it ends thus ending thread(?).
Edit - you updated your comment while I was working on reply.

Comment: @MariuszZieliński `T3 spawned by windows to run only RegisterServiceCtrlHandler()` To run StartServiceCtrlDispatcher() and its callbacks to be exact.

Comment: @MariuszZieliński Yes, exactly. `function calling it ends thus ending thread(?)` The point is StartServiceCtrlDispatcher() normally returns only after the service was finished. So T3 keeps running (inside this call) for a pretty long time.

Comment: this is exactly what confuses me. My understanding is that StartServiceCtrlDispatcher() will block and in the thread it was invoked all service related functions will run.RegisterServiceCtrlHandler() only tells which function service control dispatcher should run.So no matter in which thread you will call RegisterServiceCtrlHandler()  handler function will be executed in thread where you started dispatcher.Now when I think about it it makes sense to register handler later when working thread is ready to receive messages and only after starting dispatcher.You have to use another thread.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158749/discussion-between-matt-and-mariusz-zielinski).